# Using perl lookbehind(or lookahead) to capture word

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a series of files each of which starts with the sentence

> create tablespace *tablespace-name* data.dbf

I need to extract the *tablespace-name* and substitute data.dbf to be *tablespace-name*.dbf.

I'm new to perl, but looks like what I need is look behind (or look ahead) regex within perl.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You could try use a substitution: `s/^(create tablespace) (tablespace-name) (data.dbf)/$1 $2 $2.dbf/`

Comment: *tablespace-name* is different in each file and I have no previous knowledge of what that would be. That is why I thought it would be best to use the lookahead or lookbehind to get the word before "data.dbf" or word after "tablespace".

Comment: Ok, I see:) Then you could also try: `s/^(create tablespace) (\S+) (data.dbf)/$1 $2 $2.dbf/`

Comment: Why not just replace this? ` data` like `s/ data//`

Comment: @AbhiNickz `tablespace-name` could also contain literal `data`

Comment: @AbhiNickz, At best, that will give `create tablespace tablespace-name.dbf` instead of `create tablespace tablespace-name tablespace-name.dbf`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thanks, your solution works mostly. It fails only in cases where there is an extra space between TABLESPACE and *tablespace-name* and also when there is space between "CREATE" and "TABLESPACE". Is there a way to handle these outliers?

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, didn't read the whole wanted output.

Comment: @Peter Try this: `s/^(create\s+tablespace\s+)(\S+)(\s+)data\.dbf/$1$2$3$2.dbf/`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thank you, that works!

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Please supply that as an *answer* that others can contribute to.

Comment: @Borodin I think it is almost identical to what is included in `ikegami`'s answer.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: The differences were enough to upset `AbhiNickz`, and in this case I think we have another drive-by question from someone who has never accepted an answer to any of their five questions.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for your comment. However, if you look and understand the questions I have asked previously, though there were responses, they did not solve my issues. I have previously added the comment on what worked for this question.

Comment: Why do you keep asking if the whole world cannot help you? Please work hard to understand what we are doing here. You are cruel to say "that works!" and run away. Very many people have tried to help you and you say nothing.

Comment: For this question, I did get the answer I was looking for and I indicated that with a comment. If you go back and look at my previous questions, I have commented on what worked or if it didn't work. 
Now regarding why I keep asking: Firstly, that is none of your business. Secondly, that is what this site is about. Asking questions and getting answers. Maybe you should take the Tour yourself to figure this out.
I'm thankful to people who have answered me before, but, it does not mean I'll accept that as an answer if it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (defined( $_ = <> )) {
   s/^create \s+ tablespace \s+ (\S+) \s+ \K data (?= \.dbf \b )/$1/x;
   print;

   print while <>;
}
```

---

Technically, look-arounds and `\K` aren't needed here.

```
s/^ ( create \s+ tablespace \s+ ) (\S+) (\s+) data ( \.dbf \b )/$1$2$3$2$4/x
```

They just make things less noisy.

Comment: I think your edit contains unnecessary spaces, Don't you mean `^create\s+tablespace\s+(\S+)\s+\Kdata(?=\.dbf\s*\z)`

Comment: @AbhiNickz, That would be equivalent, but less readable. Note the use of `/x`. It makes whitespace non-significant, allowing to one to add spaces for readability just like in regular Perl code.

Comment: See this link: your regex is not working [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rlVC2J/1)

Comment: @AbhiNickz, Your test failed because you changed /x to /g.

Comment: @AbhiNickz, [Fixed test](https://regex101.com/r/rlVC2J/2) using what I actually posted.

Comment: @AbhiNickz - @ikegami used the `/x` modifier to allow arbitrary whitespace to be added for readability.